# Changing from observe_field to JQuery in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Prior to Rails 3, I used this code to observe a field dynamically and pass the data in that field to a controller:

```
    <%= observe_field :transaction_borrower_netid,
    :url => { :controller => :live_validations, :action => :validate_borrower_netid },
    :frequency => 0.5,
    :update => :borrower_netid_message,
    :with => "borrower_netid" %>
```

I'm trying to update that code to work with Jquery and Rails 3, but I can't get it to work.  I updated my **routes.rb** to include

```
  match "/live_validations/validate_borrower_netid" => "live_validations#validate_borrower_netid", :as => "validate_borrower"
```

and I'm trying to observe the field and make the necessary calls with:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
  // when the #transaction_borrower_netid field changes
  $("#transaction_borrower_netid").change(function() {
    // make a POST call and update the borrower_netid_message with borrower_netid
    $.post(<%= validate_borrower_path %>, this.value, function(html) {
        $("#borrower_netid_message").html(html);
    });
  });
})
```

but it's not working.  My Javascript and Jquery skills are severely lacking, so any help anyone could provide would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

```
$('#transaction_borrower_netid').live('change', function() {
// when the #transaction_borrower_netid field changes
// make a POST call and replace the content
        var netID = $('#transaction_borrower_netid').val();
        $.post("/live_validations/validate_borrower_netid", { borrower_netid: $('#transaction_borrower_netid').val() }, function(html) {
            $("#borrower_netid_message").html(html);
        });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `<%= validate_borrower_path %>` in quotes:

```
$.post("<%= validate_borrower_path %>", this.value, function(html) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I made the change, but that didn't resolve the issue.